# Video File to String and back - Corrupted File

Tags: java, android, file, video, fileutils

I'm writing an app that takes a 5 second video (.mp4 file) and uploads it to a server as a base64 String. The user can download the video, at which point the String should be converted back to a File.

I'm running into a problem where the downloaded File is saved, but it is slightly smaller (2 to 3 KB smaller) than the original File and is unplayable. This issue does not happen every time that a video is taken; I have been trying to find a pattern for this behavior, but haven't found one yet.

videoFile is a File created through a MediaRecorder recording. I can play back this original File without issue.

Encoding snippet:

```
//videoFile path: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Pictures/" + timestamp + ".mp4"
byte[] bytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(videoFile);
String encodedVideo = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.URL_SAFE);
```

Decoding snippet:

```
File download = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/Pictures/test_"+videoFile.getName());
byte[] decode = Base64.decode(encodedVideo, Base64.URL_SAFE);
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(download, decode);
Log.i("compare arrays",""+(Arrays.toString(bytes)).compareTo(Arrays.toString(decoded)));
```

The downloaded File is being stored in the same directory as the original File.

**Edit to clarify:**

The "compare arrays" Log statement gives a result of 0, so the arrays `bytes` and `decode` should have the same contents.

I added additional log statements:

```
Log.i("compare contents", ""+FileUtils.contentEquals(videoFile,download));
Log.i("original checksum", ""+FileUtils.checksumCRC32(videoFile));
Log.i("download checksum", ""+FileUtils.checksumCRC32(download));
```

to compare the contents of the files more directly.

The log statement comparing the arrays always returns 0, but the `contentEquals` log statement is not always true. When it is false, the checksums of the files are different. Since the byte arrays have the same contents, I believed the checksums and the actual file contents would be the same as well. This is clearly incorrect, but I don't know how to resolve this issue. Again, I have not found a discernible pattern for when the downloaded File is incorrect.

Any help is appreciated. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: everything look OK, have you checked read/write method of FileUtils is correct, skip decode, just write bytes to file, FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(download, decode, false);

Comment: @Khang.NT I tried using that line, but it didn't change anything - the File comparison still returned false. I also tried bypassing FileUtils completely and wrote my own read and write functions, but the File comparison still failed.